# Error "415 Unsupported media type" con PostMan

Tags: c#, json, asp.net, postman

estoy realizando una Web  API en .NET de carga y descarga de archivos .pdf, al realizar la petición POST usando como cliente PostMan me devuelve un error "415 unsupported media type", he intentado agregar a los headers "application/json, application/pdf" y "application/octec-stream" para poder transferir el archivo por bytes pero sigo recibiendo el error 415, me podrian ayudar?, Gracias :).

Comment: Imagino estás haciendo un POST para **subir** el archivo. Intenta con el header  `content-type: multipart/form-data`

Comment: Hola, si es un POST intente con ese header también y sigue regresando 415

Answer (score 3):

Lo siento, no tengo reputación para comentar, sólo responder. ¿Podrias compartir la firma del endpoint de la API?
Si usas "FromForm" el Content-Type tiene que ser "multipart/form-data", como indica Arriel.
Si usas "FromBody", tienes que envolver la request en formato json o xml y meter los bytes del archivo encodeados en base64, y luego deserializar a una clase con esa propiedad definida como byte[]. En este caso el Content-Type tendrá que ser json o xml, según toque.
Saludos.

Comment: Hola, Muchas gracias si uso "FromBody" me sirvió muchisimas gracias!